# Create new column in a dataframe based on matching result of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1, which stores the current registered course and the previous course taken.

| course | previous_course |
| --- | --- |
| CS201 | CS101 |
| CS201 | CS102 |
| CS201 | CS103 |
| CS202 | CS101 |
| CS202 | CS102 |
| CS202 | CS103 |

Some courses have prerequisite, which are also stored in dataframe df2 (it's one to many relationship, one course could have many prerequisite)

| course | prerequiste |
| --- | --- |
| CS201 | CS101 |
| CS202 | CS102 |
| CS202 | CS103 |

I would like to match if the previous_course in df1 is prerequisite or not, and create another column (1 or 0). Could you advise what should I do? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use indicator parameter in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), compare by `both` and cast to integers for map `True, False` to `1,0`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['course', 'previous_course'],
              right_on=['course', 'prerequiste'],
              how='left', 
              indicator='is_prerequiste')
df['is_prerequiste'] = df['is_prerequiste'].eq('both').astype(int)
print (df)
  course previous_course prerequiste  is_prerequiste
0  CS201           CS101       CS101               1
1  CS201           CS102         NaN               0
2  CS201           CS103         NaN               0
3  CS202           CS101         NaN               0
4  CS202           CS102       CS102               1
5  CS202           CS103       CS103               1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do a left [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `df1` and `df2` and then create the new column based on the joined `prerequisite` column using [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), as follows:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['course', 'previous_course'], right_on=['course', 'prerequiste'], how='left')
df3['is_prerequiste'] = np.where(df3['prerequiste'].notna(), 1, 0)


print(df3)

  course previous_course prerequiste  is_prerequiste
0  CS201           CS101       CS101               1
1  CS201           CS102         NaN               0
2  CS201           CS103         NaN               0
3  CS202           CS101         NaN               0
4  CS202           CS102       CS102               1
5  CS202           CS103       CS103               1
```